# Explain Plan in Oracle - how do I detect the most efficient query?

Tags: oracle, explain

### Intro

I am writing a query to compare 2 different oracle database tables containing hashes.

I want to find which hashes from location 1, have not been migrated over to location 2.

I have three different queries, and have written `explain plan for` statements for them.

However, the results don't tell me that much.

### Question

How do I find which is the most efficient and fastest?

### Current Guess

My suspicion however is that the first query is the fastest since it makes a one-off use of the remote link. But this is just a guess that is not supported by actual results.

### Code

```
--------------------------

EXPLAIN PLAN
SET statement_id = 'ex_plan1' FOR
select* from document doc left outer join migrated_document@V2_PROD migrated on doc.hash = migrated.document_hash AND migrated.document_hash is null ;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(NULL, 'ex_plan1','BASIC'));

---------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name              |
---------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                   |
|   1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                   |
|   2 |   REMOTE              | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DOCUMENT          |
---------------------------------------------------


--------------------------

EXPLAIN PLAN
SET statement_id = 'ex_plan2' FOR
select* from document doc where not exists( select 1 from migrated_document@V2_PROD migrated where migrated.document_hash = doc.HASH ) ;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(NULL, 'ex_plan2','BASIC'));

------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name              |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                   |
|   1 |  FILTER            |                   |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DOCUMENT          |
|   3 |   REMOTE           | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |
------------------------------------------------


--------------------------

EXPLAIN PLAN
SET statement_id = 'ex_plan3' FOR
select* from document doc where doc.hash not in ( select migrated.document_hash from migrated_document@V2_PROD migrated) ;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(NULL, 'ex_plan3','BASIC'));

------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name              |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                   |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI |                   |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DOCUMENT          |
|   3 |   REMOTE           | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |
------------------------------------------------


--------------------------
```

### Update

I updated the `explain plan` statements to get more results. 
Due to the remote operation... could something cost less but be more slow?

If I am reading the data correctly it seems that option 2 is best. 
But I still think option 1 is quicker.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Inst   |IN-OUT|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                   |   105K|    51M|   194 |        |      |
|   1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                   |   105K|    51M|   194 |        |      |
|   2 |   REMOTE              | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |     1 |   275 |     2 | V2_MN~ | R->S |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DOCUMENT          |   105K|    23M|   192 |        |      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Inst   |IN-OUT|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                   |   105K|    23M|   104K|        |      |
|   1 |  FILTER            |                   |       |       |       |        |      |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DOCUMENT          |   105K|    23M|   192 |        |      |
|   3 |   REMOTE           | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |     1 |    50 |     1 | V2_MN~ | R->S |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Inst   |IN-OUT|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                   |   105K|    29M|   526 |        |      |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI |                   |   105K|    29M|   526 |        |      |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DOCUMENT          |   105K|    23M|   192 |        |      |
|   3 |   REMOTE           | MIGRATED_DOCUMENT |     1 |    50 |     0 | V2_MN~ | R->S |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you simply select `PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)` , it displays more information such as cost and time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect world, you would choose the plan with the lowest cost. However I do not think your first query does what you want. It looks to me like no rows will join; you should be using a filter predicate rather than a join.

Instead of

```
select * from document doc 
left outer join migrated_document@V2_PROD migrated 
  on doc.hash = migrated.document_hash 
AND migrated.document_hash is null
```

it should be

```
select * from document doc 
left outer join migrated_document@V2_PROD migrated 
  on doc.hash = migrated.document_hash 
WHERE migrated.document_hash is null
```

Comment: true... I noticed that a few hours later but had to leave the office. But is the lowest cost the best one?

Comment: Providing the data (stats etc) are accurate and the cardinalities in the explain plan are representative, then the lower cost plan should be the fastest. There is one way to see... give it a go :)